# Looking for an English idiom to describe specialist employment

Tags: idiom-requests

There's a French phrase "Mais il faut recruter à l’extérieur : on ne peut pas faire des pâtissiers avec des maçons".
This translates to "However, we have to recruit outside: we cannot make confectionery using stonemasons"

It means that you cannot just take anyone to do a specific job.

Is there a similar idiom in English?

I'm thinking there must be an English idiom, but I cannot find anything online.

Comment: [A square peg in a round hole](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/square-peg-in-a-round-hole) is used when trying to make something fit where it does not belong.

Comment: [horses for courses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horses_for_courses) but this may be too narrow. If refers to differences among very similar things. Like dentists who only do root canals on some teeth, and send you to someone else for the other teeth.

Comment: Thanks for these. Interesting take on "horses for courses".  I thought it referred to a situation where one person could not understand why another would like something, sahing "horses for courses" as if to say, "rather you than  me" or "it takes all sorts to make the world"...

Comment: I think you could adapt it and it would look great, e.g. *Never hire a plumber when what you need is a pastry chef" or *Never hire a plumber to make pastry.*

Comment: If you want to use a self-deprecating tone for humorous effect, there’s “We need professional help.”  This is sometimes used as a euphemistic way of saying that a person needs psychiatric help, but in its surface reading, it says that you’re looking for a person with the right qualifications.

Comment: I can't work out if this is because the French are more likely to recruit outside than the English, or if it's so unusual in France they need a special idiom to justify it. Probably there are statistics *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very common phrase, "To use the right tool for the job."

I expect (although it's opinion,) that English speakers would recognize the phrase if "tool" were replaced with virtually any other more human-focused noun like "worker" "employee" "staff" or "person". I have often heard the phrase "He was the right man for the job."

"We had to hire outside the company; we needed the right woman for the job."

That said, I think the French phrase is more colourful, and I might start using it. "You wouldn't make a cake with a carpenter."

---

If you are looking for something more negative, there's always "You can't put lipstick on  a pig," used to imply that something's nature can't be changed by trying to force it to be what it is not.

Answer (score 0):

How about, “Never send a boy to do a man's job” or some variant thereof?

From [The Big Apple](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/dont_send_a_boy_to_do_a_mans_job):

> “Don’t send a boy to do a man’s job/work” means that one should not have someone do what that person cannot do. “Hire a boy to do a man’s business; he will make up his wages in the spoiling of your tools” was cited in 1860.

From tvtrope's [Never Send an X to Do a Y's Job](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverSendAnXToDoAYsJob) (I apologize in advance for [ruining your life](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife):

> A character is sent to take care of something another tried and failed to do, and some essential difference between the characters in question is pointed out. This often results in a stock phrase of the form "Never send a boy to do a man's job."

The only issue I see with this phrase is it connotes a sense that the "boy" doing the job is not only ill-equipped to perform the specialized job, but is not as good at jobs in general.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure this works in the original because the speaker isn't being derogatory about masons, he's just saying he needs a specialist, not a general worker. Meant without disrespect.  Interesting to see the answers though and I am grateful for your time to answer.

Comment: There is a slightly more amusing version _"Never send a boy to do a man's job, they will only steal his bike."_

Comment: I like the second version Peter :D

Comment: I'm really grateful to all the replies. I've learned a lot.  Still didn't find an idiom that was a precise fit, so just had to translate the meaning. Enjoyed the learning though so thanks to everyone for sharing thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of reflexive turn of phrase that fits this.  It comes in the for of advice commonly given to people, which is to "stick to the knitting."  It means to avoid going into a business that is beyond one's expertise.  To apply it in a structure similar to what you are after, one could say something like: 'When hiring, make sure that your prospective employees will be sticking to their knitting.'

Answer (score 0):

How about "You can't paint a house with a hairbrush?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a uniquely American trait but, in the States, people are more inclined to the opinion: "If he can do it, so can I."

Back in the old days - when things were not so disposable and one could make a living doing expert repairs of various things - there were (mostly) men who would come to your home to fix things. You could call someone to come fix your refrigerator, washing machine, furnace, television, telephone, etc. (Nowadays, there  are only electricians, plumbers, the "HVAC guy", the "pool man" and "The Geek Squad") There were even shops where you could bring your toasters, blenders, vacuum cleaners, and hair dryers for repair.

Anyway, the home repairmen of various specialties were referred to, in common parlance, as "the man". As in: "The freezer is broken - we'd better call "the man".

In answer to your question, the common phrase referencing these "experts" - often employed to discourage "do-it-yourself-ers" from making the problem worse - was also used to warn people not to "dabble" when a specialist was warranted...

To wit: "In the long run, it's cheaper to call 'the man'."

Answer (score -1):

“Retournons à nos moutons”
Let’s stick to our knitting.

Source: French-born French language teacher during a lesson at L’Alliance Française, Glasgow.

Context: The class, discussing an aspect of the lesson, had wandered away (for a time with a certain enthusiasm) from the subject. Teacher returned us to what we were supposed to be discussing by saying “Retournons a nos moutons” and said the English equivalent is “Let’s stick to our/the knitting”

Comment: This answer was [already given](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/500208/191178). Is there anything you can add to this?